# Nesting a fragment inside a bottom navigation view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a bottom nav view in the main activity with three fragments, A, B and C. I want to nest another fragment in my B fragment, but also making sure that you can still navigate back to the B fragment, and to A and C (with the bottom nav view).

I tried nesting a fragment in my B one, but it gives me an error:

```
rhythmTwo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            RhythmTwo rhythmtwo = new RhythmTwo();
            ft.replace(R.id.frame2, rhythmtwo);
            ft.commit();
        } else {

        }
    }
});
```

Logcat:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.stefanawesome.piano.MainActivity@76a0944 must implement
>   OnFragmentInteractionListener

Even if this works I'm not sure what the bottom nav view will do, I want to make sure you can still travel back to fragment B to fragments A and C. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code your fragment, When you want to go to another fragment by fragment :

```
 //signIn Screen call
    signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).login();
        }
    });
```

Put this code to your Activity where you have all three fragments :

```
 public void login()
{
    LoginFragment loginFragment = LoginFragment.newInstance();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame_home, loginFragment)
            .commit();
    toolbarTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mTitle.setText("Sign In");

}
```

Like I have also  five Fragments in Bottom Menu on Same Activity:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()== R.id.home_ll){
        homeImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_home_active);
        searchImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_search);
        categoriesImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_categories);
        cartImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_cart);
        accountImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_account);
      //  homeImg.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorPrimary));

        mTitle.setText("Bloom");
        toolbarTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment().newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame_home, homeFragment)
                .commit();


    }
    if(v.getId()== R.id.search_ll){
        homeImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_home);
        searchImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_search_active);
        categoriesImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_categories);
        cartImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_cart);
        accountImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_account);

        mTitle.setText("Search");
        toolbarTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment().newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame_home, searchFragment)
                .commit();






    }
    if(v.getId()== R.id.categories_ll){
        homeImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_home);
        searchImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_search);
        categoriesImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_categories_active);
        cartImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_cart);
        accountImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_account);


        mTitle.setText("Categories");
        toolbarTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        CategoriesFragment categoriesFragment = new CategoriesFragment().newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame_home, categoriesFragment)
                .commit();


    }
    if(v.getId()== R.id.cart_ll){
        homeImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_home);
        searchImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_search);
        categoriesImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_categories);
        cartImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_cart_active);
        accountImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_account);

        mTitle.setText("Cart");
        toolbarTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        CartFragment cartFragment = new CartFragment().newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame_home, cartFragment)
                .commit();




    }
    if(v.getId()== R.id.account_ll){
        homeImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_home);
        searchImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_search);
        categoriesImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_categories);
        cartImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_cart);
        accountImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_account_active);

        if(pref.getBoolean("login_status", false))
        {
            mTitle.setText("Account");
            toolbarTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Log.e("LOGIN","Yes");
            AccountFragment accountFragment = new AccountFragment().newInstance();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame_home, accountFragment)
                .commit();
        }
        else
        {
            mTitle.setText("Sign In");
            toolbarTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Log.e("LOGIN","No");
            LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment().newInstance();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame_home, loginFragment)
                    .commit();
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, you really helped!

Comment: Wecome @Stefan , Happy Coding